# why this solr error is returning on indexing data

Tags: solr

in solr log I see an error like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot change field "statusID" from index options=DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS to inconsistent index options=DOCS
```

I tried to delete the data from this collection using

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"delete":{"query":"*:*" }}' http://localhost:8983/solr/users_collection/update?commit=true
```

and for few hours it helped, new data was indexed and error dissapered, but after few hours I see the same error.

in the managed-schema I see this field is configured like this

```
<field name="statusID" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

What else should I do to fix this permanently? Its not a new instance of solr, it is working with multiple collections for a few years.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions